# Unable to get id of inserted record

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to insert records into a table in MySql. The table is set up like this:

- id - primary key - auto increment
- first - varchar(45)
- last  - varchar(45)

When I insert a new record I want to know the value of the id for that record.

I added this query to my tableAdapter called "insertQuery". Using `select @@identity;` to grab the id.

```
INSERT INTO `results` (`first`, `last`) VALUES (@p1, @p2); select @@identity;
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.ResultsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.myDataSet.results)

        test()

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub test()
        Dim newID As Integer

        newID = Me.ResultsTableAdapter.InsertQuery("John", "Smith")

        MsgBox(newID.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The record gets inserted correctly into the database, but the problem is the value of my newID variable is always 1.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was finally able to get it to work. All I needed to do was change the `ExecuteMode` property of the query from NonQuery to Scalar.

I had this working earlier in the week and sometime today I changed that property somehow. I was about to go crazy lol.

Comment: It's the same code. All I had to do was select the query in the tableAdapter to show it's properties in the properties window. Then change ExecuteMode to Scalar.

Answer (score 1):

use mysql_insert_id() function as shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
if ((result = mysql_store_result(&mysql)) == 0 &&
mysql_field_count(&mysql) == 0 &&
mysql_insert_id(&mysql) != 0)

{
  used_id = mysql_insert_id(&mysql);
}
```